# State of art numerical algorithm for all complex roots of high degree polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, applications, math-software

I have many polynomial with high (100+) degree. The coefficients are integer. I would like to find all the roots in $\mathbb C$ of each polynomial as fast as possible. Best complexity and best implementation are needed because I need solve very large set of them.

Note that algorithm needs to return all roots, not just one. (Well actually I would also be interest if there is some algorithm that finds not all but most root, say 80-90%, if enough speed increase to be worth.)

I have looked into several options from wikipedia's list but there are many with differing complexity and for condition other than mine.

> What is the state of the art fastest method for solving all root at once of super high degree, integer polynomial?

Second part and very related question.

> What is the fastest package or programming language to run above algorithm?

Comment: See the comment at the top of the latest version of the answer below. I'm  starting to think that the silly algorithm I made up is actually pretty good...

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** I posted a much improved version of the algorithm below on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19999/finding-all-roots-of-a-polynomial/307926#307926), together with a Python implementation  and empirical evidence that the running time is $O(\log(1/\epsilon))$ to approximate the zeroes within $\epsilon$. State of the art or not, if it's actually $\log(1/\epsilon)$ it seems like it should be good enough; hard to imagine doing much better than that.

**Edit:** I just made up the algorithm below. A comment leads to web pages showing that sure enough it's something people actually do. No surprise there, hard to see what else you're going to do. But **note** that looking at a few web sites I noticed that people worry about an important issue that I hadn't thought of: If $p$ has multiple roots (points where $p(z)=p'(z)=0$) the efficiency goes totally to hell. See **Multiple roots** at the bottom for why this is a problem and what to do about it.

What's below is surely not state-of-the-art (**edit:** maybe closer than I thought the other day). But it's very simple, and it works; also I suspect it's not *too* bad, efficiency-wise, so since you have no other answers I thought I might mention it.

At first it seemed like finding *all* the zeroes was going to involve some moderately sophisticated analysis,  like calculating integrals that count zeroes or something. But, no, I realized last night that a very simple "bisection" method works.

**Note** it seems likely that what's below could be improved, at the cost of adding complexity to the code: Use the bisection below until you're fairly close to all the zeroes and then switch to Newton's method. This would require a little math to devise a test for when to switch - you don't want to switch until you get to a point when Newton is guaranteed to converge. More on that later if I figure it out. Meanwhile, the bisection works like so:

Say $$p(z)=\sum_{j=0}^n a_j z^j$$with $a_n\ne 0$. Let $$R=\max\left(1, |a_n|^{-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|a_j|\right).$$Then $|z|>R$ implies $p(z)\ne0$, so if you set $$Q_0=[-R,R]\times[-R,R]$$then you know all the zeroes lie in $Q_0$.

Now set $$\delta=\sum_{j=0}^n j|a_j|(\sqrt 2R)^{j-1},$$so that $$|p'(z)|\le\delta\quad(z\in Q_0).$$

Now you maintain a finite collection of squares. At each iteration you refine this collection: Divide each square into four subsquares.  "Test" each subsquare, rejecting it or accepting it; the new collection consists of all the accepted subsquares.

To "test" a square $Q$: Say $a$ is the center of $Q$ and $r$ is the distance from $a$ to a corner of $Q$. If $$|p(a)|>r\delta$$it follows that $p$ has no zero in $Q$; in that case reject $Q$, otherwise accept it.

Now if $K_k$ is the union of the squares accepted at the $k$-th stage it follows that $K_k$ converges to the zero set of $p$.

Proof: Say $S=\bigcap_k K_k$. Since each rejected square contains no zeroes of $p$ it follows that the zero set is contained in $S$. Conversely, say $z\in S$. Then there exists a sequence $Q_k$ such that $Q_k$ is one of the squares accepted at the $k$-th stage, $Q_{k+1}\subset Q_k$, and $\{z\}=\bigcap_k Q_k$. Now since $Q_k$ passed the test, $$|p(a_k)|\le\delta r_k\to0;$$since $a_k\to z$ this shows that $p(z)=0$.

**Multiple roots:** Things blow up in the presence of multiple roots. Why: Imagine first that $p(z)=z$.  I believe it's easy to see that at each stage there will be exactly four accepted squares, no problem. But now assume $p(z)=z^2$. The problem is that there will be a huge number of squares where $p$ is very small, although the squares contain no zeroes of $p$. In fact it seems to me that for large $k$, at the $k$-th stage there wiil be $c2^k$ accepted squares - very bad.

**Fix:** Implement the division algorithm, giving quotient plus remainder for the quotient of two polynomials. Use that with Euclid's algorithm to find $d=gcd(p,p')$. Let $q=p/d$. Then $q$ has the same complex zeroes as $p$, *except* that all the zeroes of $q$ are simple.

**Some good news:** At first I thought that the fix wouldn't work in floating-point, so you'd need to implement exact calculations in $\Bbb Q[x]$, which would be a slight pain in an environment with no built-in rational data type. But on second thought I believe that you *can* do it using floating point (if you *do* have exact rational arithmetic handy it's not clear to me which would be more efficient.)

The (non?)-problem: Say $\tilde d$ is your floating-point approximation to $d=gcd(p,p')$. Then $p$ is not exactly divisible by $\tilde d$, so you're sunk. No, I think this is ok. The division algorithm gives you $p=\tilde d\tilde q+r$. Now, $r$ would vanish if not for roundoff error, so $r$ will be small. Hence $\tilde q$ gives a good approximation to $q=p/d$,  and it follows that the zero set of $q$ is appproximated by the zero set of $\tilde q$ (and also that the zereos of $\tilde q$ are simple, if the roundoff error is small enough).

Comment: Other keywords are Weyl scheme, bisection-exclusion method, inner root radius computation via Dandelin-Graeffe iterations, see for instance https://perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/yak/files/2012/04/yak_05_bissection_analysis.pdf

Comment: Other methods that follow the domain subdivision path are the [Lehmer-Schur algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%E2%80%93Schur_algorithm) and Schönhage's [Splitting circle method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_circle_method) (see also the referenced papers for inspired methods).

Comment: There are all-at-once iteration methods like the [Durand-Kerner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand%E2%80%93Kerner_method) and [Aberth-Ehrlich methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberth_method). Multiple or close-by roots result in linear, straight paths of the root approximations so that a cluster analysis can detect them and accelerate convergence. There are papers by V. Pan about this and other algorithmic improvements.